# jQuery event fails when a new div is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, here is my javascript:

```
$().ready(function (){
$(".contact").hover(function (){
    ...
});
$(".contact").not('.contact[id="'+activeId+'"]').click(function (){
    ...
});
$(".contact_chooser_contact").click(function (){
    ...
    $('.contacts').append('<div class="contact" id="'+id+'" title="'+phone+'">\
                                <div class="contact_img"><img src="src/default_face.png" width="64"/></div>\
                                <div class="contact_info" id="'+name+'">'+name+' <span class="sms_number">0</span></div>\
                                <div class="contact_last_sms">\
                                \
                                <!-- span class="last_sms_time"> echo $message[sizeof($message)-1]->time; </ -->\
                                </div>\
                            </div>');           
    ...
});
});
```

Notice, how in the "contact_chooser_contact" click handler, I append another ".contact" in ".contacts", but now when I hover over that new ".contact", it doesnt do anything like it is supposed to. How can I fix this problem, I understand that its because I havent reinitiated the '$(".contact").hover()' after I added the new ".contact", but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the event with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), using this will bind any element added to the DOM with the respective selector. The advantage of using `on()` over `live()`, is that you can narrow down the context to a specfic container, rather than the entire `document`. In my example, I just use the `document` as the context.

jQuery **1.7** use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.contact', function(){
  ...
});
```

Less than **1.7**, use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate('.contact', 'mouseover', function(){
   ...
});
```

Less than **1.4.2**, use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.contact').live('mouseover', function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: Note: `.on()` only has the `.live()` type of behaviour if you pass a selector as the second parameter. If you just say `.on('click',function(){})` it will be the same as `.click()`. Also, if you're on less than version 1.7 use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - only use `.live()` if you're on less than version 1.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I normally only use `on()` since I don't need the future selectors, but I had not even read up on delegate.

Answer (score -1):

".contact" add event when the document onload. after, the div added from ".contact" 's event doesn't have event in fact. because the click event don't execute again.

you can do like this:

```
function addDiv(div) {
    div.hover(function() {
        ...
    });
}

$(function() {

    addDiv($(".contact"));

    $(".contact_chooser_contact").click(function (){
        addDiv($('<div/>').addClass('.contact').attr({id:ID, title: TITLE}).append(...));
    });
});
```